# Swift to Kotlin: Enums

Tags: enums, kotlin

Been working at this conversion, but each attempt is yielding nothing but errors.  I can provide my attempts, but given how many different ones I've made, I think it's more beneficial to see if anyone has a direct solution for this.

I have considered using a 'sealed-class', but not entirely sure if it's necessary for this situation.  Looking to learn anything I can.

Swift code:

```
enum Type: Equatable {
case full
case fixed(height: CGFloat)
case scrollView(estHeight: CGFloat)
case flex(prefHeight: CGFloat)

var height: CGFloat {
    switch self {
    case .full: return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    case .fixed(let height): return height
    case .scrollView(let estHeight): return estHeight
    case .flex(let pref): return pref
    }
}

static func == (lhs: Type, rhs: Type) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.full, .full),
         (.fixed, .fixed),
         (.scrollView, .scrollView),
         (.flex, .flex):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
}
```

All I need is a solid example of how to approach this.  Not looking to have the entire thing provided in Kotlin; but if it's worth doing, that is fine too.

Thanks!

Comment: You should at least provide your Kotlin code to show what work you have done/tried.

Comment: In most cases I would agree with you.  This was an exception for me, given my numerous attempts with incorrect syntax.  I felt it was more beneficial to leave the code open to feedback, rather than attempt to fix my incorrect approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned a `sealed class` might be a good option.

Like this:

```
sealed class Type

object Full : Type()
data class Fixed(val height: Double) : Type()
data class ScrollView(val estHeight: Double) : Type()
data class Flex(val prefHeight: Double) : Type()

fun Type.height(): Double = when (this) {
    is Full -> 1.0 // Screen.main.bounds.height
    is Fixed -> height
    is ScrollView -> estHeight
    is Flex -> prefHeight
}
```

**Note 1:** Instead of `sealed class Type` `interface Type` could be used, but in that case the compiler is not able to check `when` for completeness.

**Note 2:** There is no need to implement `equals` like in the example given. `object` and `data class` implement `equals` correctly.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to satisfy the cross-over.  They syntax is really what was killing me.

Your also correct about the Equatable stuff.  I figured I didn't need it, but left it in regardless.  This makes total sense now, I appreciate it.